# How to change properties values of child classes

Tags: java, polymorphism

This is a general question. I can not find the proper answer probably because I don't know what to write in my browser in order to get good results:

If I have one class A

```
    public abstract class Base {
        String prop1;
        int prop2;
    }
```

I want to create two subclasses B and C that extend A:

```
    public class B extends A {
        String prop3;            
    }

    public class C extends A {
        String prop4;            
    }
```

The main class

```
    A b = new B();
    A c = new C();
```

My question. How can modify the value of properties prop3 and prop4?

When I write b., the intellisense only shows the prop1 and prop2 for autocompletion and I cannot write for example b.prop3 because I get an error. I try using a cast like (B)b. and I get the same result.

Comment: You'll have to either declare b & c as type B & C Or cast them as B & C. (Assuming you have a getter/setter method for the properties, or the properties are declared public)

Comment: I do it this way because I want to use them (B and C) in the same Array. I also tested  something like A b = (B)new B(); I do have getter and setters

Comment: Well, when you try to access properties of `b` the compiler only sees `A b`, i.e. it doesn't know whether `b` references an instance of `B`, `C` or anything else (it can't be `A` because that's an abstract class but that doesn't matter here). Thus the only common part is that all instances have prop1 and prop2. If the compiler (and intellisense) are meant to allow prop3 or prop4 you have to tell it that `b` actually refers to an instance of `B`, i.e. `B b` or `((B)b).prop3` (note that the compiler would accept `((C)b).prop3` as well but you'd get a class cast exception at runtime).

Comment: Normally you're supposed to turn to a polymorphic approach in this situation. Or just set the objects' properties *before* you put them in the array.

Comment: You should re-read the chapter on how inheritance works in Java. When you make an instance of a base class, it will not inherit the methods and data from B or C, only the base class, because you are using the constructor from that  class when you write: A b = new B(); If you wrote B b = new B() you would be using the constructor of the B class.

Comment: The problem is that I didn't include the parentheses.  ((B)b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because I get an error. I try using a cast like (B)b. and I get the
>   same result.

It helps to read the errors. Do you get a class cast error? A property not visible error? and unrelated error due to a typo?

Reading the error will tell you exactly.

Right now you declared 'a' and 'b' as class 'A'. In order to access properties of class 'B' and 'C' you'll have to either cast the variables as 'B' & 'C', or declare them as 'B' & 'C'.

Also, you did not declare a getter/setter and the variables are by default, package-private. This means you cannot access the variables from outside the class.

Assuming for example B does have a getter for 'prop3', you can use:

```
((B) b).getProp3();
```

To avoid the class cast warning, you could do:

```
if (b instanceof B)
{
    ((B) b).getProp3();
}
```

However, whenever you need to do the above you should rethink your design. Try to avoid it whenever possible

Comment: It works fine now, the problem was that the enclosing parentheses were important ((B) b)